# Refactoring of this massive ViewController with a UITableView in it

Tags: swift, ios

I'm making an application that has a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` in order to show the favorite users that the user of the app have added. They are being stored in `UserDefaults`, for which I have created a `UserDefaultsManager` struct to handle its logic.

I had the following ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class FavoriteListViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Private Properties
    
    private let tableView = UITableView()
    private var favorites: [User] = []
    
    
    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureViewController()
        getFavorites()
        configureTableView()
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        getFavorites()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Private Methods
    
    private func configureViewController() {
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        title = "favorites".localized()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    }
    
    private func configureTableView() {
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.frame = view.bounds
        print(tableView.frame)
        tableView.rowHeight = 80
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        tableView.register(GFFavoriteCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: GFFavoriteCell.reuseId)
    }
    
    private func getFavorites() {
        UserDefaultsManager.shared.retrieveFavorites { [weak self] result in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            
            switch result {
            case .success(let favorites):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.updateUI(with: favorites)
                }
                
            case .failure(let error):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.presentGFAlert(title: error.title, message: error.description)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func updateUI(with favorites: [User]) {
        if favorites.isEmpty {
            view.showEmptyStateView(with: "FavoritesListViewController.empty_state".localized())
        } else {
            self.favorites = favorites
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.tableView)
        }
    }
    
}

// MARK: - Delegates

extension FavoriteListViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return favorites.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: GFFavoriteCell.reuseId) as! GFFavoriteCell
        var favorite = favorites[indexPath.row]
        favorite.avatarImage = try? ImageManager.retrieveImage(for: favorite.username)
        cell.set(favorite: favorite)
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let favorite = favorites[indexPath.row]
        let destinationVC = UserListViewController(username: favorite.username)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard editingStyle == .delete else {
            return
        }
        
        UserDefaultsManager.shared.update(with: favorites[indexPath.row], actionType: .remove) { [weak self] error in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            if let error = error {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.presentGFAlert(title: error.title, message: error.description)
                }
                return
            }
 
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.favorites.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        UIView(frame: .zero)
    }
    
}
```

I have refactored it and broken it down into the files listed below:

**FavoriteListDataSource**

```
import UIKit

class FavoriteListDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

    // MARK: Public Properties
    
    var favoriteRepository: FavoriteRepository {
        return FavoriteRepository()
    }
    private weak var delegate: FavoriteListDelegate?
    
    // MARK: - Initializers
    
    init(delegate: FavoriteListDelegate?) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }
    
    // MARK: - Protocol Methods
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return favoriteRepository.favorites.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: GFFavoriteCell.reuseId) as! GFFavoriteCell
        var favorite = favoriteRepository.favorite(at: indexPath.row)
        favorite.avatarImage = try? ImageManager.retrieveImage(for: favorite.username)
        cell.set(favorite: favorite)
        
        return cell
    }
        
    func tableView(
        _ tableView: UITableView,
        commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle,
        forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath
    ) {
        UserDefaultsManager.shared.update(
            with: favoriteRepository.favorite(at: indexPath.row),
            actionType: .remove
        ) { [weak self] error in
            
            guard let self = self else { return }
            if let error = error {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.delegate?.showError(title: error.title, message: error.description)
                }
                return
            }
 
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
                self.delegate?.handleEmptyView()
            }
        }

    }
    
}
```

**FavoriteListDelegate**

```
import UIKit

protocol FavoriteListDelegate: AnyObject {
    func didSelectRow(at index: Int)
    func handleEmptyView()
    func showError(title: String, message: String)
}
```

**FavoriteListView**

```
import UIKit

class FavoriteListView: UIView {
    
    // MARK: Private Properties
    
    private let tableView = UITableView()
    private var dataSource: FavoriteListDataSource!
    private weak var delegate: FavoriteListDelegate?

    // MARK: - Initializers
    
    init(delegate: FavoriteListDelegate) {
        super.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        
        self.delegate = delegate
        dataSource = FavoriteListDataSource(delegate: delegate)
        
        backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        configureTableView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    // MARK: - Public Methods
    
    func reloadData() {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    // MARK: Private Methods
    
    private func configureTableView() {
        addSubview(tableView)
        
        tableView.frame = bounds
        tableView.rowHeight = 80
        
        tableView.dataSource = dataSource
        tableView.delegate = self
        
        tableView.register(GFFavoriteCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: GFFavoriteCell.reuseId)
    }
    
}

extension FavoriteListView: UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        delegate?.didSelectRow(at: indexPath.row)
    }
    
    // Hides the empty cells from the TableView
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        UIView(frame: .zero)
    }
    
}
```

**FavoriteListViewController**

```
import UIKit

class FavoriteListViewController: UIViewController, HasCustomView {

    // MARK: Protocol Typealias
    
    typealias CustomView = FavoriteListView
    
    // MARK: Private Properties
    
    private var favoriteRepository: FavoriteRepository {
        return FavoriteRepository()
    }
    private var favoriteListView: FavoriteListView!
    
    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    
    override func loadView() {
        favoriteListView = FavoriteListView(delegate: self)
        view = favoriteListView
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureViewController()
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        favoriteRepository.refresh()
        handleEmptyStateView()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Private Methods
    
    private func configureViewController() {
        title = "favorites".localized()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    }
    
    private func handleEmptyStateView() {
        if favoriteRepository.favorites.isEmpty {
            view.showEmptyStateView(with: "FavoriteList.empty_state".localized())
        } else {
            favoriteListView.reloadData()
            view.hideEmptyStateView()
        }
    }
    
}

// MARK: - Delegates

extension FavoriteListViewController: FavoriteListDelegate {
    
    func didSelectRow(at index: Int) {
        let favorite = favoriteRepository.favorite(at: index)
        let destinationVC = UserListViewController(username: favorite.username)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
    }
    
    func handleEmptyView() {
        handleEmptyStateView()
    }
    
    func showError(title: String, message: String) {
        presentGFAlert(title: title, message: message)
    }
    
}
```

**FavoriteRepository**

```
class FavoriteRepository {
    
    // MARK: Properties
    
    private(set) var favorites: [User] = []
    
    // MARK: - Initializers
    
    init() {
        fetchFavorites()
    }

    // MARK: - Public Methods
    
    func favorite(at index: Int) -> User {
        return favorites[index]
    }
    
    func refresh() {
        fetchFavorites()
    }
    
    // MARK: Private Methods
    
    func fetchFavorites() {
        UserDefaultsManager.shared.retrieveFavorites { [weak self] result in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            
            switch result {
            case .success(let favorites):
                self.favorites = favorites
                
            case .failure:
                self.favorites = []
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

I'm aware that there is much more code than before, which is something that I would be fine with as long as I follow the SOLID principles and the code scales appropiately, but I have the feeling that some things are not quite right. For example, I have a `favoriteRepository` computed property in the `ViewController` and in the `DataSource` in order to respond appropiately to the case where the user removes a favorite user directly from the list by sliding the cell and tapping on delete. I'm not sure if that's the best way to handle that because both classes are accessing the same repository from a different object and I have to recur to computed properties to resolve that.

As I said, that's only an example, but I suspect that there are a few more things that might be improved. I would be very grateful to read any criticism of my code in order to refactor it the proper way as I'm trying to get over massive ViewControllers.

It might be worth noting that I don't use the `DataSource` in any more ViewControllers.